# POST request error (possibly related to allow origin access)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am having a problem when I try to test an API POST request from my device. Here is my code:

```
let link = "http://example.com";                 
      var payload:any = {                  
          password: this.password,
          email: this.email,                  
      };
      var headers:any = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      this.http.post(link,JSON.stringify(payload),{headers: headers}).
      subscribe(data=>{
        if(data.success){
         //if valid
        }else{
          //if not valid
        }
      });
```

Here is the error:

> console.error: EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0 for URL: null

I added Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but it does not resolve the error. When I tested it, it shows everything fine in a browser, but on the device it returns an error. Any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Comment: Did you add the CORS option on the server side. Which server are you using? Secondly, if you are testing it on Device, it shouldnt be a CORS situation unless you added some restriction on the server. How are you testing with the device

Comment: yes i added it in server side, problem happen when i add header in ionic post request

when i remove it it is work but i need the header to send authontication for example

Comment: this may happen if device is not online, try posting some seconds after connected?: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network/